# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error is showing when i submit my form

Tags: python, mysql

this is my app.py code
The error is on line 33
I have made a html form which submits basic details like name, father name and so on  but when i fill the form the entries made doesn't show up in mysql database.

```
from os import name
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'Karan1234'
  
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'K@r@n!23$'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'login_register'
  
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'Name' in request.form and 'F_name' in request.form and 'M_name' in request.form and 'M_tongue' in request.form and 'Native' in request.form and 'Occupation' in request.form and 'Gender' in request.form and 'M_status' in request.form:
            Name = request.form['Name']
            Father_Name = request.form['F_name']
            Mother_Name = request.form['M_name']
            Mother_Tongue = request.form['M_tongue']
            Native = request.form['Native']
            Occupation = request.form['Occupation']
            Gender = request.form['Gender']
            Marital_Status = request.form['M_status']
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE Name=%s AND F_name=%s AND M_name=%s AND M_tongue=%s AND Native=%s AND Occupation=%s AND Gender=%s AND M_status=%s",(Name,Father_Name,Mother_Name,Mother_Tongue,Native,Occupation,Gender,Marital_Status))
            info = cursor.fetchone()
            if info['Name'] == Name and info['F_name'] == Father_Name and info['M_name'] == Mother_Name and info['M_tongue'] == Mother_Tongue and info['Native'] == Native and info['Occupation'] == Occupation and info['Gender'] == Gender and info['M_status'] == Marital_Status:
                return "registration successful"
            else:
                return "registration unsuccessful"
            

    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Line 33 is the if-statement where you check `info` for different keys. However, as the error tells you, a object of `NoneType` is not subscriptable. That means that `info == None`, which means that the row before the error didn't return the result you wanted.

Comment: @HampusLarsson so what could be the solution here?

Comment: Why do you think that your cursor didn't return any value? It might be because there isn't a row in the table you're searching that matches against all of those statements.

Comment: @HampusLarsson ok

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the query in line 31 returned no records. So info in line 32 is None.

You can just check if info is None before parsing or add a try except block before line 33. Like this...

```
try:
    if info['Name'] == Name and info['F_name'] == Father_Name and info['M_name'] == Mother_Name and info['M_tongue'] == Mother_Tongue and info['Native'] == Native and info['Occupation'] == Occupation and info['Gender'] == Gender and info['M_status'] == Marital_Status:
        return "registration successful"
    else:
        return "registration unsuccessful"
except:
    print('No Records found')
    return
```